# ViewFlipper with onclick

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I'm doing a layout where different content will be display in one place.

[image]

Example:
When click on button 1 the context will display in box A
and if I click on the next button4 the contant will also display in box a

I am using the ViewFlipper for this below is the xml code

```
<ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dip" >

            <include
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            layout="@layout/a1" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            layout="@layout/a2" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            layout="@layout/a3" />

        </ViewFlipper>
```

below is the onclick listener I use

```
a1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            viewFlipper.bringChildToFront(myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.ghfristd));

        }
    });
```

but nothing seen to appear.

if Viewflipper is not adviseable to use in the example image i provided what will be adviseable. any suggestion is welcome

Comment: displaying layout or a fragment ?

Comment: intially i am display content by using the DialogFragment but its like kind of messy and annoy to some user so i am try to display the content in the same place. hope this help. i'm not good with words .sry

Comment: ViewFlipper is view flipper it means it flips views not dialogs.

Comment: Murtaza sry about it. what i mean was that previously i was using dialogfragment to pop up the content to use. but now i am trying to use viewflipper to display the contant in the same location. dont know if this is advise able anot. if not could you advise me what will be good to use.

Comment: ViewFlipper works like a slideshow which you can play or pause. If you need to show content in succession then it is best to use.

Comment: ohh thanks for the enlightment. for what example image i show above. like when user click on button 1 and the conte\nt is shown in box a and later click on button 4 and the content is also shown in box a . what will you suggest?

Comment: You can do that with ViewFlipper too. The answer below will surely help you.

Comment: so for the index i will like r.id.a2?

Comment: No, Assume your id `android:id="@+id/a1"` is place first so its index is `0` and so on

Comment: Thanks i got it working at last. if possible could you enter a simple answer so that i can vote it as the answer?.btw just 1 more quesiton. if i want to auto run like some slideshow is this do able with viewflipper?

Comment: yes you can do that too. you can use `startFlipping()` to auto flip your views. You can read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ViewFlipper to show a particular child view then you should use

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(index);
```

Where index is the child's index.

Comment: for this i got different layout link to the a1 and a2 and a3. so like a1 is link with button 1 and when click on button 1 it will display the content which is link with a1. this goes on for the other 3 as well